# How to return record to a store of a different js file in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am trying to create a pop up editing on a grid in extjs4. So far I was able to transfer the record from the grid to a popup panel which is on a different js file. I did it using this code:

```
handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex){
var record = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
var frm = new MyDesktop.Modules.Journals.Client.JournalsDetailForm();
frm.createWindow(desktop, record, operation);
```

the other file accepts the record like this

```
jvdetailform.loadRecord(record);
```

Now my problem is after editing the record from the pop up form, how do I return the record back to the store once I press the add button on my jvdetailform, then automatically update the grid?

Comment: You need to accept answers from your previous questions.

Comment: done. now, back to my question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In button handler of you form:

```
var values = this.getValues(); // where this == jvdetailform
record.set(values);
```